# How to change tensor definition without getting a new name assigned in the graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter

I am loading some previously saved models and running through a series of tests.  The previously saved models each have a tensor called 'embedding', however the embedding tensor is a different shape in each model.

When I try to load the second model sequentially, I re-declare the embedding tensor with the new expected shape, but when I try to load the model it is still trying to use the previous definition.

```py
for embed_dim, embed_path in zip(modeldims, modelpaths):
    embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((n_vocab, embed_dim), -1, 1, name='embedding_layer')

    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(sess, modelpaths[0])
        valid_embedding = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, valid_dataset)
        embedding_result = valid_embedding.eval()

        # do some stuff with the embedding result
```

This works on the first iteration, but on the second iteration, I get the error:

```
NotFoundError: Key embedding_layer_1 not found in checkpoint
```

And when I accidentally declare the embedding tensor incorrectly and go back to correct it by redeclaring, then it still uses the old definition of embedding_layer (i.e. the corrected version is being declared as embedding_layer_1 so it still doesn't match)

```
InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match.  
lhs shape= [156786,50], rhs shape= [156786,100]
```

Is there a way to reuse tensors in this way?  At the moment I am restarting the kernel for each model load - feels like there must be a better option?